# nix::sched::clone cause segmentation fault after println

Tags: linux, rust, system-calls

I'm trying to manually create thread by calling `clone`. The following code cause segmentation fault, but if I remove `println!` before sleep the code runs fine.

```rust
use nix::sched::{self, CloneFlags};
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

fn task() -> isize {
    println!("from inside thread");
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(2));
    0
}

fn main() {
    const STACK_SIZE: usize = 1024 * 1024;
    let ref mut stack: [u8; STACK_SIZE] = [0; STACK_SIZE];
    let cb = Box::new(|| task());
    let flags = CloneFlags::CLONE_VM
        | CloneFlags::CLONE_FS
        | CloneFlags::CLONE_FILES
        | CloneFlags::CLONE_SIGHAND
        | CloneFlags::CLONE_THREAD;

    sched::clone(cb, stack, flags, None).expect("clone error");
    println!("created thread");
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(5));
}
```

additional information: My actual goal is experimenting with linux namespace and I want to create threads in different uts namespaces, so I need to be able to pass `CLONE_NEWUTS` when calling `clone`.

Comment: File an issue on their github- segfaults are a symptom of undefined behavior, and the `nix` crate is supposed to be safe, ie not allow safe rust to cause undefined behavior.

Comment: @Aiden4 You are right. Upon looking at their issues I found that this is still an open issue [here](https://github.com/nix-rust/nix/issues/360)

Comment: That's what I figured- you can try one the the mentioned workarounds, or if you are feeling adventurous, attempt to fix the issue in the library itself.